# When to use remember in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

On the official site, there is no exact information, on what cases we should use "remember{}".

1. Should we remember arithmetical operations if they repeat multiple times in the code? Or if it is only one operation but very complex?
2. Also what about the classes of Android Compose - RoundedCornerShape, TextStyle, BorderStroke, SolidColor, FocusRequester, KeyboardActions, KeyboardOptions, Gradient?
   When we use it while creating an object(ex. RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)) multiple times (in different places in the code or the cycle(creates multiple objects in the same composable functions)? Does it make sense to remember these objects while single using?
3. When we make some transformation with a list of data, mapping smth?

How to know when it is useful for caching while recomposition and when it is redundant?

Answer (score 10):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

You use remember in Android Compose when you want to remember the value.

**LONG ANSWER:**

The mechanism works as follows when a state variable changes then recomposition is triggered, and you see the updated screen on your mobile.

**For example:**

`Case 1`

```
@Compose
fun MyComposable(){
    var text: String = ""
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            text = newText
        }
}
```

In this case: when you press a button on your keyboard nothing is happening because you do not have a state value that compose mechanism looks in order to update your screen. *In this case when you press a letter on your keyboard nothing happens at all.*

`Case 2`

```
@Compose
fun MyComposable(){
    var text by mutableStateOf("")
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            text = newText
        }
}
```

In this case you have a state variable (in our case a string), and when you press a button on your keyboard recomposition is happening. So the mechanism says hey look the value has changed, let me recompose the screen with this composable then the block runs again, and `text` variable defaults to an empty string(`""`) again. So even though recomposition happened you see the same thing on your screen.

`Case 3`

```
@Compose
fun MyComposable(){
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            text = newText
        }
}
```

In this case lets say you want to type the number `10` on your keyboard. You click `1` mechanism sees the state value has changed. Then mechanism executes composable function again when at text value it does not default it to `""` but keeps or remembers the `1` you pressed before. So you see `1` on your screen and you can press `0` and see 10 finally...

`So when is useful to use remember?` Since the block of a composable may run several times and in unexpected ways, you should use a `remember{}` when you want your variable to survive this `re-execution of code`. In other words if you have a constant value you do not care and you do not want to remember it. On the other side if you want an animation to happen you want the value to be remembered between two points so remember should be use. For complex calculations of course it is better to transfer this code to a `ViewModel` as stated from @nglauber.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding about `remember`...

1. You should use `remember` for values you want to be remembered across recompositions. I don't think that simple math operations worth it to be remembered and complex operations should be done on other parts of the app like a View Model or Use Case (preferably in a separate thread).
2. Let's break up this question in parts:

   2.1. Shapes, Colors and TextStyles should be declared in your theme. See [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-create-a-truly-custom-theme-in-jetpack-compose-55fb4cd6d655) how to do this. Therefore, you wouldn't need to remember.

   2.2. The object KeyboardOptions is not kept in memory. It is converted to IME options, so I think remember it is not a good idea.

   2.3. KeyboardActions, maybe... But in terms of legibility I wouldn't do that...

   2.4. For `FocusRequester` makes sense to me remember it, otherwise you will attach a new `FocusRequest` to the components on each recomposition. Which might cause an unexpected behavior (focus jumping here and there)...
3. Yes. But, as I mentioned above, this operation should not be done on the composable. It can be done on View Model or in other layers... Composable should received the list ready for use.

Comment: "The object KeyboardOptions is not kept in memory", KeyboardOptions is a class, how to check it when call KeyboardOptions() not recreated while recomposition? And what if to call KeyboardOptions().copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number), Doest it create object two times? 

Should we remember object while call copy()?

Comment: I said that because if you go through the calls from `TextField` to the implementation, the `KeyboardOptions` object is converted to IME options. To be more precise, in `BasicTextField` composable when it is calling `CoreTextField`. So, I think it is created when the recomposition happens, but I think it is not kept in memory.

Comment: @nhlauber, The more remembering of creation objects(event is not kept in memory) the fewer recompositions have occurred and therefore the better performance of the composable function. Is that make sense?

Comment: No, recomposition is related to state changes. `remember` is related to object assignment/reassignment. You can remember an object (not necessarily a state) in order to avoid its re-initialization during a recomposition. Keep in mind that a composable function can called several times, if you don't remember that object, it will be recreated on each composition.

Answer (score 0):

- `remember` usually tells the compiler that the compose will have to remember the value passed to it.
- Because if it does not remember it, it will execute the lambda on every recomposition

**Example**:

```
@Composable
fun rememberSnackBarState(): SnackbarState {
    return remember { SnackbarState() }
}

class SnackbarState {

    var success by mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
        private set

    var error by mutableStateOf<Exception?>(null)
        private set

    private var updated by mutableStateOf(false)

    fun addSuccess(message:String){
        error = null
        success = message
        updated = !updated
    }

    fun addError(exception: Exception) {
        success = null
        error = exception
        updated = !updated
    }

}
```

**Usage**:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MessageBarComposeTheme {
                val state = rememberSnackBarState()
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```