# What's does State and Stateless mean in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm relatively new to compose and while learning about it I hear the word "state" and "stateless" a lot, but it's not well defined. It probably is, but I still don't get it. I was reading the docs about [state management](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting). I think I have a basic understanding of the theory side of recomposition, and how you have to update the "state", for the UI to update because it's immutable. Where I'm stuck is in the practice. Like, **what does updating the *state* mean exactly**, and **what does it mean when a composable is *stateless*?**

I know this might be asking for a lot, but I'm dumb, and if you could explain it like I was 5 years old I would greatly appreciated it.

Comment: compose does recomposition based on comparing the previous state with new state. so when a state changes it recomposes some of them and it skips some of them. https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/donut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose and this https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd will help!

Comment: Gotta love it when someone does a "-1 drive-by" and doesn't even say why.

Comment: It wasn't me. But i guess the reason is question needed a bit of code sample rather than a link

Comment: Yeah maybe. But, I'm not coding yet. I wanted to understand the theory before putting it into practice. Whatever my doubts were cleared and that's all I care :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image below is a screenshot of a simple Android App.

[image: Screenshot]

Let's see the explanation of state that is provided in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#:%7E:text=State%20in%20an%20app%20is,connection%20can%27t%20be%20established.):

> State in an app is any value that can change over time.

We notice that the TextField and Text value **both depend on the user name that is entered**. Thus, our App actually has only one core value that can change over time, which is the **user name**.

Now that we identified that our App state primarily includes the user name, let's start writing some code:

```
MainComposable() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        Text(
            text = "My App"
        ) 

        var userName by mutableStateOf("")

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            value = userName,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                userName = newText
            }
        )
   
        Text(
            text = "Hello " + userName + "!"
        )

    }
}
```

Note that in the TextField, we update the `userName` variable with the currently entered text. 
 **Whenever we update the `userName` value variable, we actually update the state.**

In order to refresh the rest of the user interface whenever the `userName` state changes, we need to wrap this variable with `mutableStateOf` and `remember`. 
Whenever we assign a new state to a variable that we declared using `mutableStateOf`, Jetpack Compose will automatically **refresh** all parts of the user interface that **depend on that value**. This is called **recomposition**.

During recomposition, any variables values in the Composable that is recomposed would be **reset**. To avoid that resetting of state variables, we use `remember`.

So in summary, we use

- `mutableStateOf` to tell Jetpack Compose that a variable is a "state variable". Jetpack Compose will then notice any changes made to that variable and update the dependent Composables accordingly
- `remember` to not lose the current value of the state variable when the surrounding Composable is recomposed.

---

A Composable that declares a state variable is a `stateful` Composable. In our case, the `MainComposable` is stateful, as it declares the `userName` variable. 
 If instead, the `userName` variable was passed in as a parameter, our `MainComposable` would be stateless.

```
// STATEFUL
@Composable 
fun MainComposable() {
     //...
     var userName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
     //...
}

// STATELESS 
@Composable 
fun MainComposable(userName: String, userNameChanged: (newUserName: String) -> Unit) {
     //...
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful! While I have you here, I have a few more questions.

What does `remember` do? I've seen it used, as you demonstrated, `remember { mutableStateOf("") }`  and like this  `remember {someValue}`. What's the difference between one and the other?

Comment: I edited my post. Also check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72057390/8331157 
It points out the purpose of `mutableStateOf` and `remember` pretty well. Within the brackets of `mutableStateOf`, you just set the initial value that the state variable should have.

Comment: Yes, this is excellent. Very clear and easy to digest. And, we want stateless composable because it makes them reusable and easier to test. Right?

Comment: there is rememberSaveable to save state during configuration change. Check it in case it helps

Comment: True. I found out about that as I read more on `remember`.

Comment: @Jcorretjer Exactly, when a Composable is stateless, we are passing in the state with variables, and thus we can recuse that Composable with different input parameters. Also, we can test how the Composable behaves with different input parameters.