How is TextField 's "onValueChange" parameter updated in Jetpack Compose
Having this simple example:
@Composable
fun SimpleFilledTextFieldSample() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        label = { Text("Label") }
    )
}

I'm trying to understand if every time a user presses a key "onValueChange" is updated (meaning called)?
I'm having trouble finding the answer in the android jetpack compose documentations..

Regarding onValueChange, the documentation states "is triggered when the input service updates the text". And regarding the variable: Well, it is the one and only variable you have in your example: var text. Since all this is obvious and self-explanatory I don't think that is what you actually wanted to know. Please [edit] your question and clarify what the real issue is.

what is the input service? The main question was simple. If I write "something" if the onValueChange is 's' and then 'so', 'som' etc.

That comment doesn't clarify, it is even more confusing: What does "If I write "something" if the onValueChange is 's' and then 'so', 'som' etc." even mean? This isn't a question or a statement, it isn't even a  full sentence. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you don't understand about the variable text containing the value of the TextField.

Maybe this answer you could find it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72057390/6805392

Your understanding is correct. Whenever the text in the TextField is modified, onValueChange will be called with the whole current text.
When you type "ABC" into the empty TextField, the onValueChange callback will return
A
AB
ABC

The TextField documentation says

onValueChange: (String) -> Unit 
the callback that is triggered when the input service updates the text. An updated text comes as a parameter of the callback

They are using the rather generic "Input Service" term here as there a various ways to generate text into a TextField, also known as IME:

on-screen keyboard
speech-to-text
physical keyboard
...

Whenever an IME generates or changes the text in the TextField, onValueChange is triggered. It is then your job to update the value variable with the fresh text to correctly update the UI.
